Entity Framework Core returning null values for non-nullable properties
I'm using Entity Framework Core 8 with ngpsql to interact with a Postgres database. Everything has been working as expected until now, but I've recently run into an issue that has me totally stumped.
In short, queries are returning null values for properties that are not nullable.
Here is a sample data object I'm storing:
public class Sid : IBaseDataClass
{
    // ...
    public required WaypointDescription WaypointDescription { get; set; }
    // ... 
}

For the record and should it matter, IBaseDataClass looks like this.
public interface IBaseDataClass
{
    public SourceLabel Source { get; set; }
}

WaypointDescription is defined as follows:
[Owned]
public record WaypointDescription
{
    public required WaypointDescription1 WaypointDescription1 { get; init; }
    public required WaypointDescription2 WaypointDescription2 { get; init; }
    public required WaypointDescription3 WaypointDescription3 { get; init; }
    public required WaypointDescription4 WaypointDescription4 { get; init; }
}

Each of the WaypointDescription1-4 are simple enums.
Data is being loaded in the database as expected, and when I query the data I see values in all the columns where I would expect them to exist.
However, even something this simple:
var record = db.Sids.First();

if (record.WaypointDescription is null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Null value");
}

Is printing the null value message. This seems... impossible?
I thought perhaps there was something going on with lazy loading going haywire, but I forced eager loading of that column with an Include() and it still shows up as null.
It's not just that one property, others that should have data and are non-nullable in other record types are null as well.
I've turned on query logging and the raw SQL being used looks correct -- It does a by-column select of every column from the table.
I'm truly baffled on this one and feel like I must be missing something fundamental but I have no idea what it is.
Does anyone have an idea what might be going on?

Do you have a full repro?

A full repro due to the length of the code required to instantiate a Sid record won't fit in this comment box.  However, Program.Main can consist of nothing more than connecting to the database with nothing but a connection string, newing up a new Sid with a valued WaypointDescription populated in it, Add()ing that to the database, SaveChanges(), and then the same query I showed in my original post to extract the record.  Checking for a null on the WaypointDescription of the returned record returns true.
